# how to concat parameters with other values in report query wizard

Tags: mysql, ireport

I have below query in Report query wizard of iReport

```
select docid_fname_pemid.*, MONTHNAME(b.ServicePeriodDate) as month_name,YEAR(b.ServicePeriodDate) as year_name , b.NonLTCMaximumSpecialPayment, b.NonLTCEnrolledPatientOutsideUseTotal, b.NonLTCAccessBonus
from (
select docid_pemid.PEMID, docid_pemid.DoctorID, b.$P{transparency_check})
from (
select DoctorID,PEMID from DoctorPEMMap where PEMID in ($P{PEMID_input}) and StartDate >= $P{StartDate}  and (EndDate <= $P{EndDate} or EndDate <= '0000-00-00') group by PEMID order by PEMID
)docid_pemid   left join  Doctors b on docid_pemid.DoctorID=b.DoctorID
) docid_fname_pemid
left  join DoctorPayments b on docid_fname_pemid.DoctorID=b.DoctorID
```

& parameters,as in order (Parameter class, Prompt Yes/NO, Default value Expression)

1)`PEMID_input`--> string, prompt yes, no

2)`month_year`--> .String,prompt yes, no

3)`transparency_input`--> String,prompt yes, no

4)`transparency_check` -->String,No prompt,`($P{transparency_input}=="yes" ) ? ("FirstName") : ("AliasFirstName")`

5)`StartDate` -->String,No prompt, `$P{month_year}.split("-")[0]=="April" ? $P{month_year}.split("-")[1].concat("-04-01") :   $P{month_year}.split("-")[1].concat("-10-01")`

6) `EndDate` -->String, No prompt, `$P{month_year}.split("-")[0]=="April" ? $P{month_year}.split("-")[1].concat("-09-30") : $P{month_year}.split("-")[1].concat("-03-31")`

when I run report,give below error

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''FirstName' 
from (     select DoctorID,PEMID from DoctorPEMMap where PEMID in ('21' at line 3
```

at

I think query not getting `'b.FirstName'`. So I used concat function as `concat('b.',$P{transparency_check})`, but it not works.

I want ultimately `b.FirstName` or `b.AliasFirstName` as in mysql query.when any one of this terms I give manually,query runs fine.

How should I go ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having has to do with the way that Jasper inserts parameter values.  If you use just $P{PARAMETER NAME}, then I believe it fills in the parameter after compiling the SQL.  If you use $P!{PARAMETER NAME}, the parameter is treated as a literal and is filled in before compiling the SQL.  This is why Jasper appears to be inserting single quotes around the parameter value when you use $P only.

So try changing this:

```
b.$P{transparency_check}
```

To this:

```
b.$P!{transparency_check}
```

And remove the extra parenthesis after transparency_check.

Check this link.  I think it explains it better than I can.

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-report-parameters

Here is what the entire code should look like.  I formatted it to make it a little easier for me to read.

```
SELECT  docid_fname_pemid.*, 
        MONTHNAME(b.ServicePeriodDate) as month_name,
        YEAR(b.ServicePeriodDate) as year_name , 
        b.NonLTCMaximumSpecialPayment, 
        b.NonLTCEnrolledPatientOutsideUseTotal, 
        b.NonLTCAccessBonus

FROM 

(
    SELECT docid_pemid.PEMID, docid_pemid.DoctorID, b.$P!{transparency_check}

    FROM
    (
        SELECT  DoctorID,
                PEMID 
        FROM    DoctorPEMMap 
        WHERE   PEMID IN ($P{PEMID_input}) 
                AND StartDate >= $P{StartDate}
                AND (EndDate <= $P{EndDate} or EndDate <= '0000-00-00') 
        GROUP BY PEMID 
        ORDER BY PEMID
    ) docid_pemid   

    left join  Doctors b on docid_pemid.DoctorID=b.DoctorID

) docid_fname_pemid

left  join DoctorPayments b on docid_fname_pemid.DoctorID=b.DoctorID
```

Comment: ,I did same,but when retrieving fields automatically,gives same "Error:null"
I ignore that & proceeds further to run.It runs when given transparency_input="yes",but when I give transparency_input="no",error occurs->Error filling print... Unknown column name : FirstName 
Setting up the file resolver...

I want dynamic value of transparency_check to be either "FristName" or "AliasFirstName",which depends upon transparency_input("yes"/"no") parameter (look in question in parameter section)

Comment: Is my syntax to check condition for transparency_check is correct ?

Comment: It looks right to me, although java kicks my butt all the time.  It looks like it is working correctly as the error message referred to "first_name".  Test it out.

Comment: You appear to have had any additional parenthesis after tranparency_check as well.